# Where can I find apxs on amazon linux?

Tags: linux, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to get started with an AWS website, and used the free tier Amazon Linux installation. I installed python3.3 from source, but the wsgi it comes with is for python2.6 so I tried installing mod_wsgi3.3 from source as well, at which point I get

```
./configure --with-python=/usr/local/bin/python3
checking for apxs2... no
checking for apxs... no
checking Apache version... ./configure: line 1704: apxs: command not found
./configure: line 1704: apxs: command not found
./configure: line 1705: apxs: command not found
./configure: line 1708: /: is a directory

./configure: line 1877: apxs: command not found
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: error: cannot find input file: Makefile.in
```

and for the life of me, I have not found a single helpful online source to tell me how to get apxs installed on this system. Suggestions have all been for ubuntu, and hence `sudo apt-get install apache2{}-dev` where '{}' can be replace with nothing, or `-worker` or `-threaded` or `-prefork`; none of these have worked on my system (using `sudo yum install` instead).

Is there a different package name I should be looking for? If so, what is it/where do I find potential packages? `sudo yum search apache` doesn't yield any `apache2`.

Please help.

Comment: With redhat based systems, you will find the apache packages named httpd.

Comment: ahh, ok, that's gotten me a bit further. `./configure` now worked, but `make` is having reading `lpython3.3`, getting a `Bad value`.

Comment: Try https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/archive/feature/3.5.tar.gz rather than the last mod_wsgi release tar ball. Some Python installations add a suffix to the library and last official release isn't handling it properly.

Comment: I tried with the old (the last release) and the one you've provided (thanks, btw!) and now I'm getting `[ec2-user@ip-172-31-43-211 mod_wsgi-feature-3.5]$ sudo /etc/init.d/httpd start
Starting httpd: httpd: Syntax error on line 204 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /etc/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: libpython3.3m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. My python was installed in `/opt/python3`; how do I get sudo to recognize that PATH (or LD_LIBRARY_PATH, or LD_RUN_PATH)? Very new to all of this!

Comment: @datasage;Charles engelke, that did the trick, so feel free to post that as an answer and I'll accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

First of all if you are using Amazon Linux or any RPM based linux distro, you should use "httpd" rather than "apache2". Apache use in Debian family.

I think you can resolve this issue by installing httpd-devel package.
Try 
`yum search httpd-devel` 
and choose required version and then do `yum install httpd-devel <package version>`

Sometime just firing `yum install httpd-devel` can do the job.

Comment: If you're using Apache 2.4 you will need the `httpd24-devel` package.